# How do I create a join in Fluent Nhibernate on two non-key properties whose names do not match?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have two tables in my legacy database

Purchases

- Id int(PK)
- name varchar(50)
- MasterAccount char(10)
- BuyerAccount char(10)

MasterAccounts

- Id int(PK)
- Name varchar(50)
- MasterAccountNumber char(10)
- AccountNumber char(10)

I have an object that maps 1:1 to the purchases table. I want to add the "Name" column from the MasterAccounts table to the purchases object as a property.

How do I tell Fluent Nhibernate to perform a join when the two columns I want to join on:

1. are not defined as foreign keys in the database
2. Do not have the same name in each table

It might be helpful to see the SQL that I want to generate.

```
Select Purchases.*, MA.Name
from Purchases
left join MasterAccounts MA
on 
MA.MasterAccountNumber = Purchases.MasterAccount
and
MA.AccountNumber = Purchases.BuyerAccount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `MasterAccount` field in *Purchases* matches the `MasterAccountNumber` in *MasterAccounts*...create a view in sql with the table format you are trying to map:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_PurchaseMasterAccountName]
AS
SELECT     dbo.Purchases.Id, dbo.Purchases.Name, dbo.Purchases.MasterAccount, dbo.Purchases.BuyerAccount, dbo.MasterAccounts.Name AS MasterAccountName
FROM         dbo.MasterAccounts INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Purchases ON dbo.MasterAccounts.MasterAccountNumber = dbo.Purchases.MasterAccount
```

Create a ClassMap to map your view:

```
public class Purchase
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string MasterAccountName { get; set; }
    public virtual string MasterAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual string BuyerAccount { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseClassMap : ClassMap<Purchase>
{
    public PurchaseClassMap()
    {
        Table("v_PurchaseMasterAccountName");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.MasterAccount);
        Map(x => x.BuyerAccount);
        Map(x => x.MasterAccountName);
    }
}
```

Ensure your ClassMap is picked up in your FluentMappings.

**UPDATE:**

This may work instead:

```
public class PurchaseMap : ClassMap<Purchase>
{
    public PurchaseMap()
    {
        Table("Purchases");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.MasterAccount);
        Map(x => x.BuyerAccount);
        Map(x => x.MasterAccountName).ReadOnly()
            .Formula("(SELECT TOP 1 MasterAccounts.Name FROM MasterAccounts WHERE MasterAccounts.MasterAccountNumber = [MasterAccount] AND MasterAccounts.MasterAccountNumber = [BuyerAccount])");

    }
}
```

Thanks to Darren Kopp for the pointer to the Formula option.

Comment: This *would* work, except that we can't create a view in our in-memory test database on our build server. We're using SQLCE. This is what we did initially. So I'm trying to do this in Fluent NHibernate.

Comment: Agreed on the not updateable. Updated my map with your idea on the formula as readonly. Btw, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Yup, the formula was the easiest way to do this. I know there is another way, but this will do for now.

Comment: This is not unusual at all when you deal with financial systems.  But I need a better answer.  Formula is ugly and will not join to full types.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an unusual question and there may very well be other options, but here's my couple of ideas.

1. [Use a formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312722/nhibernate-how-to-map-a-property-to-a-subselect). The property wouldn't be updateable but in your situation i think that's fine (mark property as read only).
2. I think you will have to do a hbm.xml file for this, but you can [use your own query for the loader query in nhibernate](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-load).
3. Figure out what Subselect on the JoinPart does in fluent nhibernate? Doubt this will work but worth a try